# Change left and right handles of a keyframe using blender python

Tags: python, animation, scripting

[image]

I have this code that selects a particular fcurve (Z location in this case) and moves a single keyframe.

However, the keyframe handles don't get updated and are all messed up.

The python tooltip is incomplete and doesn't work as well.

[image]

```
import bpy

# Configuration
action_name = 'CubeAction'
data_path = 'location'
index = 2                # Z axis

# Find the appropriate action
action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
if action:
    # From this action, retrieve the appropriate F-Curve
    fcurve = action.fcurves.find(data_path = data_path, index = index)
    if fcurve:
        
        fcurve.keyframe_points[1].co.x += 2
            
        print("changed")
    else:
        print("no fcurve")
else:
    print("no action")
    
print("end")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

# Configuration
action_name = 'CubeAction'
data_path = 'location'
index = 2                # Z axis

# Find the appropriate action
action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
if action:
    # From this action, retrieve the appropriate F-Curve
    fcurve = action.fcurves.find(data_path = data_path, index = index)
    if fcurve:
        
        kps = fcurve.keyframe_points[1]
        kps.co.x += 2
        kps.handle_left[0] += 2
        kps.handle_right[0] += 2
            
        print("changed")
    else:
        print("no fcurve")
else:
    print("no action")
    
print("end")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

When the tooltip is incomplete, turn to the manual, in this case the entry for [`Keyframe`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html)  where you will find entries for [`handle_left`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html#bpy.types.Keyframe.handle_left) and [`handle_right`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html#bpy.types.Keyframe.handle_right).

All you need to do is add

```py
fcurve.keyframe_points[1].handle_left[0] += 2
fcurve.keyframe_points[1].handle_right[0] += 2
```

to your code.

Comment: Thank you for the manual suggestion.